# Nested For Loop C++

Tags: c++

Can some one please point out what is causing the nested for loop to not be executed in the below code sample. The "for (int j = 40; j < =0; j-=5)" loop is not being executed.

```
void printTable(int windS, int windL) 
{
    for (int i = windS; i <= windL; i+=5)
    {
      for (int j = 40; j <=0; j-=5)
      {
         cout << "  " << windChill(j, i);
      }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It probably should be `j >= 0`.

Comment: programming is based on logic. you should **think** about things before expecting the machine to just do what you want.

Comment: also, turn on warnings. a good compiler would have probably warned you about the tautological (or rather contradictional) condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because:

```
for (int j = 40; j <= 0; j -= 5)
```

will never execute. The `j <= 0` will start as `40 <= 0` which results in `false`.

What you probably meant was:

```
for (int j = 40; j >= 0; j -= 5)
//                 ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

`int j=40` is an initializer

then follows condition `j <=0` which is never true. You probably meant `j>=0`

And the action to perform on each iteration `j-=5`